# Private Shared Folder

Tags: server, permissions, samba, password, adduser

Good day,
I have a question regarding my private shared folder.

I add already a user called 'private'
something like this:

```
lhon@lhon-server:~$ sudo adduser private
Adding user `private' ...
Adding new group `private' (1006) ...
Adding new user `private' (1004) with group `private' ...
Creating home directory `/home/private' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password:
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for private
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Full Name []: Lhon Private
        Room Number []:
        Work Phone []:
        Home Phone []:
        Other []:
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
```

after I've created user and folder using

```
sudo mkdir /home/private/personal
```

```
[LhonPersonal]
comment = Contents are private.
path = /home/private/personal
read only = no
guest ok = no
create mask = 0666
force user = private
force group = private
force create mode = 0666
directory mask = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
```

when I browse into my windows network I put 'private' on the username and my password but the folder still not accessible?
thanks

Comment: Did you add user as a Samba user?

Comment: thanks I use this

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```
works fine.  thanks so much